# Input from html5 using form and search in multiple columns in sqlite

Tags: python, html, sqlite

I am working on a project in which i need to search within multiple columns in sqlite5.

I will ask user to enter source and destination (using form in html5) use python on backend and I want to search route no. which will transit between those two stands.

My sqlite table is in format -

```
RouteNo. Stop1 Stop2 Stop3 Stop4....
```

So I have to attempt a query which will be like

```
Select Routeno. from (Table name) 
where (Stop1='src' Or Stop2='src' Or Stop3='src'....) 
AND   (Stop1='dest' Or Stop2='dest' Or Stop3='dest'....)
```

assuming src is source entered by user and dest stands for destination.

**Which sql query can help me to traverse though all columns?**

Comment: Use rows rather than columns in another table: `table_stops [routeNo, StopNo]` then its a simple select.

Comment: can you please explain more?